# Polymer - positioning paper-fab?

Tags: css, polymer, floating-action-button

I'm trying to make a Polymer `paper-fab` (floating action button) go in the bottom right corner of the screen.  I also want it to disappear on scroll down but then come back on scroll up (like on the Google+ Android app).  How do I do those 2 things? Here is the test site: http://www.infinitech.org/beta.  Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Do you know if you found a "better" solution then the one @A. Dueppen suggested? It feels like paper-fab should have some kind of "system" to at least position itself as "floating".

Comment: @user2422321 Not at the moment.  His answer seems to be the best workaround for it.

Comment: do you found a solution to show/hide the fab on scroll events in polymer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positioning, you will have to use `position: absolute` and top/bottom/left/right values. For the disappearing on scroll down, you would probably have to use scroll events and CSS transforms. I'm not the best at either so there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 13):

For positioning:

```
<style>

    paper-fab {
        position: fixed;
        right: 25px;
        bottom: 30px;          
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the position even scrolling, use `position: fixed` and the left/top/right/bottom stuffs.
Here is the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Adding to a previous answer...

To fix the scroll down issue, set the `z-index` CSS property to some number greater than 1.

```
<style>
  paper-fab {
    z-index: 2;

    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;          
    right: 25px;
  }
<style>
```